# Creating Image from uicontrol without xaml in Windowsphone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm saving a Grid as Image to Isolated storage so it can be used on a tile. However this only works if the Grid is defined in xaml. When created in C# the actual Height and Width is always 0. I'd like to call this method from the backgroundtask to update my tile, but you can't define xaml there. Is there a way around this?

```
public void SaveImageFromGrid(Grid g, string fileName)
    {
        int w = Convert.ToInt32(g.ActualWidth);
        int h = Convert.ToInt32(g.ActualHeight);
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(w, h);
        wb.Render(g, null);
        wb.Invalidate();
        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
            {
                myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(fileName);
            }
            IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(fileName);
            StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
            Uri uri = new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Relative);
            sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
            Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` are calculated after a rendering pass and take into account the overall layout. Since you're not rendering the Grid, the values would be zero. If I understand correctly, you're creating the Grid programmatically so you could simply set and use the `Width` and `Height` values instead.